# Use jquery to move a td in a tr

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a way to dynamically move a `td` from one place to another (within the same `tr`).

Please have a look at this fiddle that demonstrates my problem and also some psuedo-code.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qsys7/847/

I hope to be able to loop through all `td`´s and check for images in this manner:

```
$('#original > tbody  > tr').each(function(index, value) {     
    var tdToMove;
    // Check if elem has an image as a child
    //if so, move it...
});
```

Comment: And, having checked for images, then what do you want to do? Please ask the full question in the question; don't expect us to go to JS Fiddle - or any other site - to try and derive the question you didn't take the time to ask.

Comment: Sorry, i´ll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like following.

```js
$('#original > tbody  > tr').each(function(index, value) {
    var td = $('td:first', this);
    $(this).append(td)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="original">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="http://mario.nintendo.com/img/mario_logo.png" alt="" width="100" height="65" /></td>
      <td>Mario</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="http://www.mariowiki.com/images/thumb/a/a0/Ice_Luigi_artwork.jpg/150px-Ice_Luigi_artwork.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="65" /></td>
      <td>Luigi</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can check if a row has an img, i hope it helps

```
 $('#original tbody  tr').each(function(index, value) {
        if($(this).children("td").children("img").length > 0){
        console.log("there is a img")
        }
        // Check if elem has an image as a child
        //if so, move it...
    });
```